# Why when setting a custom notification sound, no notification sound plays?

Tags: windows-11

If I use Windows 11's default notification sound, it plays. However, when I use a custom sound, it doesn't play. Why?

Comment: Which filetype is the file you want to use as a custom notification sound? .wav?

Comment: @Gantendo Yes, .wav.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sound-files are in a supported format and resolution ...

A workaround (that sometimes works) is saving your custom settings as a theme.

My observation is that otherwise Windows 11 randomly resets/merges personalizations like Windows-Sounds, Mouse-Cursors and similar settings that are available in the Windows 10/11-native Settings, as well as in the classic .msc/.cpl-configuration-modules.

For example when enabling disability-specific settings i have to save these changes explicitly as a theme after the initial sync/merge with the Microsoft-Account completed and the system rebooted - this i need to repeat after every quality-rollup/feature-update, else it will be reset to the status of the settings applied before this setup or the default-theme.

While not a direct answer, i hope it helps to workaround the problem and/or investigate it further.

Note: Please be aware that UWP-apps do not utilize the classic system-sound-events and are not affected by changes you make by pointing to custom files via the classic Sound-properties for notification-events.

Officially supported Themes:

[Desktop Themes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop-themes-94880287-6046-1d35-6d2f-35dee759701e) page from Microsoft listing the supported themes available via the Windows Themes Settings and/or the Microsoft Store